# Assistance with returning value based on cell being populated with number

Tags: openoffice.org, openoffice-calc

Hello and thank you for looking at my post. I am a super noob at spreadsheets but need to automate part of a cost spreadsheet in open office calc after my assistant has repeatedly managed to forget to enter the right data. Here we go:

PART 1

```
Output is in cell D1.

I have a column of cells A1 to A10, if there is a number (any number) in one or more cells from A1 to A3 then I need the D1 to equal cell B1
+ 1. 

If there is also a number in A4 to A6 then this supercedes the previous formula and D1 will now be B1 + 2. 

Lastly if there is a number in A7 to A10 then again all previous code is superceded and D1 is now B1 + 3.
```

PART 2

```
I have cells C1 to C3. If D1 equals B1 + 1, C1 will equal D1 if greater than 3, else it will be 3. C2 and C3 must be 0 or empty.

If D1 equals B1 + 2, C2 will equal D1 if greater than 4, else it will be 4. C1 and C3 must also be 0 or empty.

If D1 equals B1 + 3, C3 will equal D1 if greater than 5, else it will be 5. C1 and C2 must also be 0 or empty.
```

To me this seems almost impossible, I've spent all day trying to learn IF and ELSE statements and ISNUMBER and many other approaches and I've run out of options. Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated and if I haven't been clear please ask me to clarify any point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find a column where you can put some other formulas, for example column E.  Breaking the formula into parts will make it easier.

In E1, put `=IF(E4, 3, IF(E3, 2, IF(E2, 1, 0)))`.
In E2, put `=OR(ISNUMBER(A1),ISNUMBER(A2), ISNUMBER(A3))`.
In E3, put `=OR(ISNUMBER(A4),ISNUMBER(A5), ISNUMBER(A6))`.
In E4, put `=OR(ISNUMBER(A7),ISNUMBER(A8), ISNUMBER(A9), ISNUMBER(A10))`.
Then the formula for D1 will be simply `=B1 + E1`.  This is part 1 in the question.

For part 2, the requirement of "C2 and C3 must be 0 or empty" should not be needed, because they will be empty if D1 equals B1 + 1 anyway.  So this is all that is needed:

In C1, put `=IF(E1=1, IF(D1>3, D1, 3), "")`.
In C2, put `=IF(E1=2, IF(D1>4, D1, 4), "")`.
In C3, put `=IF(E1=3, IF(D1>5, D1, 5), "")`.

Comment: Thanks for your time will give it a go later today and let you know how I go.

Comment: Ok, after changing the commas to semicolons I get no error but it's not quite right, If I add a number to any of the cells in column A it returns true but does not supercede the earlier cells. For example we put a number in cell A1 it will return true in E2 and E1 will be 1, however I then enter a number in cell A4 as well and although E3 is true it does not change E1 to 2 as it should? Thoughts? EDIT: On further investigation it works but just backwards, eg A6 supercedes A7.

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean.  To fix the problem, please see revised formula for E1 in my answer.

Comment: That did it, thank you so much this will genuinely prevent a mistake that has repeatedly cost my business money. In case your interested its being used to select a certain sized excavator to hire based on the weight of a product we install and applying the correct amount of extra hours for travel to the hours we need the digger, resulting in the total cost. Now completely automated. Thanks again.